# Linux command (Calculating the sum)

Tags: linux, shell, command

I have a .txt file with the following content:

```
a  3 
a  4 
a  5 
a  6 
b  1 
b  3 
b  5 
c  9 
c  10
```

I am wondering if there is any command (no awk if possible) that can read the .txt file and  give the following output (Sorted by the second column):

```
c  19
a  18 
b  9
```

Comment: Are you looking specifically for a command, or is a shell script enough?

Comment: Why don't you want  awk?

Comment: Chris Beck: a shell script is enough

Comment: There is no problem with (awk) jackman. I have used (awk) "to much" in my code and i was wondering if there were other ways to do the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` piped to `sort`:

```
awk '{sums[$1] += $2} END {for (i in sums) print i, sums[i]}' file | sort -rnk2
c 19
a 18
b 9
```

`sums[$1] += $2` is adding value of `$2` in an array `sums` that is indexed by field #1 (`$1`).

`sort -rnk2` is reverse sorting numerically output of `awk` on field 2

Comment: Thanks anaubhava for your response. I would like to know if there is any other command than (awk) that can give the same result.

Comment: Can be done in a `while read` loop also but what's problem with `awk`?

Comment: There is absolutely no problem with (awk) anubhava. I have used (awk) "to much" in my code and i was wondering if there were other ways to do the same thing

Comment: Yes as I said above a `while read` loop can also do this but `awk` is shortest and cleanest.

Comment: Thanks for your response anubhava. Its much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use can use this code:

```
cat 1.txt | awk '{arr[$1]+=$2}END{for (var in arr) print var," ",arr[var]}' | sort -rnk 2
```

Explanation:
`cat 1.txt` - read 1.txt file with content

`awk` - is a language very useful for data manipulation

`{arr[$1]+=$2}` for each line in content file increase array item with key first field with value of second field. Field separator by default is space.

`END{for (var in arr) print var," ",arr[var]}'` - after all line is proceeded, print array content

`sort -rnk 2` - reverse numeric sort on field 2

Comment: You're right. 
But for me very convinient use cat as first statement.


For example, i need to manipulate data.
At first i need to knew what a file format
`cat access.log | tail -1`
Then i want to grep only this hour records 
`cat access.log | tail -1`
`cat access.log | grep 09/Sep/2015:22 `
and after i grep all interesting records i run awk on this data.

Yes, it is overkill, but this way i need edit only end of string, not a head also.

Comment: Thanks for your response BaZZiliO. Its much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Non-awk solutions.

perl

```
perl -lane '
    $sum{$F[0]} += $F[1]
} END {
    $, = "  "; 
    print $_, $sum{$_} for reverse sort {$sum{$a} <=> $sum{$b}} keys %sum
' file.txt
```

bash version 4

```
declare -A sum
while read key val; do (( sum[$key] += $val )); done < file.txt
for key in "${!sum[@]}"; do echo "$key  ${sum[$key]}"; done | sort -rn -k2
```

Answer (score 0):

non-awk challenge accepted

```
vars=$(cut -d" " -f1 nums | uniq); paste <(echo "$vars") <(cat <(sed -e 's/  /+=/' nums) <(echo "$vars" | sed 's/$/;/') | bc) | sort -k2,2nr
c       19
a       18
b       9
```